# Apache httpd: Change Content-Type of global redirect to application/json

Tags: apache, httpresponse, virtualhost, httpd.conf, http-redirect

I have an Apache 2.2 http server running on my machine for testing purposes. All it does on a specific port is redirecting to an external site.

The VirtualHost section in my httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName localhost
    Redirect / http://www.google.com
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I do this, the resulting http response has

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

But I would like the Content-Type to be `application/json`. Is there any way to achieve this?

I've found [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/setting-content-type-with-mod-rewrite) question in which the answer was to use `Header set Content-type ...`, but this didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use "always" modifier to make sure it happens in all cases, in this case you need it.

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName localhost
    Redirect / http://www.google.com/
    Header always set Content-Type "application/json"
</VirtualHost>
```

and you will get something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 18:30:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-type: application/json
Location: http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: hello,but if i only want to apply it to a special directory,how should i do ? for example: i want to change all the .js file to "application/json" in special path *.com/foo
thanks

Comment: Create a directory tag and use the same directive then, Header directive can be used in directory context too.